# How to integrate OnPrem Azure DevOps Server with the cloud one?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

My firm has the Azure DevOps online version where we have all our projects and repo's. We were not able to configure CI/CD for the repo's because our internal server network doesn't have access to the internet.

To overcome this issue, we built a new server that has access to the internet and also to the internal network. On the new server, we installed and configured Azure DevOps Server 2019. We don't want to migrate our repo's from the cloud version to the online version.

I am trying to link the OnPrem repo to the cloud repo but it was not working. I issued a PAT on the cloud version and added it as a service connection under Pipelines in the OnPrem version but still, I am not able to see and link the cloud repo's.

I can clone the repo from the cloud to the OnPrem server but that will not get the latest code as the code is being checked in the cloud repo's

Can anyone please guide me on how to link both of them, please.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a meaningful way to integrate Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server, as they are essentially the same product. I assume (but don't know) that you're looking to integrate Azure DevOps Services to on-premise builds and deployments, as you state that you want to keep the repos in Azure DevOps Services. So, in essence, you want to run build and deployment group agents in on-premise environment.

Take a look at the agent-documentation and especially the communication subsection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops

Or this old blog post, from which the communication section originates:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deploying-to-on-premises-environments-with-visual-studio-team-services-or-team-foundation-server/

The ideal solution would probably be that you run self-hosted build agents in your server that's open to internet, and configure an agent pool for them in Azure DevOps Services. For deployments, you'll want to use Deployment Groups and install deployment group agents to target servers, where they'll just need outbound 443 access for communicating with Azure DevOps Services.

If that's not possible, you'd have to install deployment agents to the build machine, which then sees your other on-premise servers, but this is rather unsatisfactory solution since you'd either have to rely on WinRm capabilities for deployments, or expose too much network between your build server and other on-premise servers.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me the right way. I was able o resolve my issue by configuring a build agent on the op-prem server and linking it to the Azure DevOps.